# Create PDF File, Attach in Out

Tags: excel, vba, email-attachments

Please help.

My code below should do the following:

1.Save Sheet1 as a PDF file.  No problems here

2.Outlook should get the recently saved PDF file and attach in new mail ready to send.

Thanks in advance,

JW

**I am using MSoffice 2013**

```
Sub Create_PDF_Attach_In_outlook_And_Send ()

    Dim outlookOBJ As Object
    Dim mItem As Object
    Set outlookOBJ = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set mItem = outlookOBJ.CreateItem(olMailItem)


    Sheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
    Filename:=Sheet1.Range("L7").Value

    With mItem
    .To = Sheet1.Range("O8").Value
    .CC = Sheet1.Range("O9").Value
    .Subject = Filename
    .Attachments.Add **????**
    .Body = "Enter Body Text"
    .Display

    End With

    Set outlookOBJ = Nothing
    Set mItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You already have the `Filename` from before: `Sheet1.Range("L7").Value`.

Comment: ^ [`Attachments.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) just needs the full path of the file.

Comment: What's in L7 - just the filename, or the full path?  You should use the full path.

Comment: I am very new with coding. So I will take time to understand.... i have tried ```Attachments.Add "Filename"```  I am getting a run time error

Comment: @TimWilliams could you please write a code example of what you mean with inserting the path?

Comment: There's no code to write - it only involves putting the full path (eg "C:\folder\file.pdf" instead of just "file.pdf") in L7 if you're not already doing that.